# How to change or add theme to Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, themes

I have just installed Android Studio in my Window 7 64bit.
When I launch the application the background of the screen where we write the code is white.
I would prefer black or any other color.
I am not sure whether we can change the color/theme OR add more themes.

Comment: for window 7 64 bit. we need to add System Variable JDK_HOME with value c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\

Comment: I didn't in fact i am happy your working in anew fresh tool like android studio.

Comment: Java code style chage to 'IntelliJ  Light' when i upgrade to studio4.1.   So I change back to  my favorite 'Classic Light'  after lots of searching.  Mac: preferences->Editor->Color Scheme->Java ->Scheme , on the right panel

Answer (score 767, accepted):

`File->Settings->Editor->Colors & Fonts->` In scheme name select Darcula and apply to see a awesome dark background theme editor

Android Studio 3.1.2 
`File->Settings->Editor->Color Scheme->` In scheme name select Darcula and apply to see a awesome dark background theme editor

Comment: How I can reset this theme, I want to get back for white theme

Comment: @MahdiAlkhatib The name of default theme is `default`, so go back to your settings and go back to your old theme.

Comment: To go back to white theme you have to change in Appearance --> Theme as well.

Comment: Easy, isn't it?! In Eclipse I had to do unspeakable witchcraft ceremonies to get  a mediocre dark theme.

Comment: Easy isn't it??!! In Eclipse, I had to do unspeakable sorcery to obtain a dark theme not half as good as this one.

Comment: Why **Darcula**??  I don't like it.

Comment: I did this on a mac and the text editor became black but I had to restart android studio for it to take effect on the menu bar at the top.

Comment: Files-->Settings-->Appearance & Behavior-->Appearance-->UI Options(Theme)

Comment: This doesn't seem like a complete answer to the question.

Comment: to install new Theme on Mac go to `Preferences -> Plugins -> Browse Repositories ->` Select Category `"UI"` and search theme name, I recommend `"Material Theme UI"` click on the green button `"Install"` and then restart after installation.

Comment: It is 5/31/2017 and Darcula is still one of the worst dark themes I have ever had the misfortune of temporarily installing on my computer. I went to http://color-themes.com/

Comment: From a user stand point of view which theme is better for eyes? Which theme should I use for healthy eyes?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky Because Dark + Cool + Dracula

Comment: You can get themes compatible with android studio as [IntelliJ plugins](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/search?canRedirectToPlugin=false&correctionAllowed=true&orderBy=&pr=androidstudio&search=theme) just another way to browse what @AamerShahzad said

Comment: black theme make me unhappy , am i alone ?

Answer (score 469):

You can download new themes from https://github.com/sdvoynikov/color-themes -- note that the project is deprecated at this time, but the sources are still available.

Once you have downloaded the `.jar` file, go to `File -> Import Settings...` and choose the file downloaded.

Comment: Thanks a lot. [Solarized Light](http://www.ideacolorthemes.org/themes/83/) is the best theme I think.

Comment: I did that to install the RecognEyes theme from ideacolorthemes, but after restarting Android Studio it is the same Darcula theme. Can somebody help me?

Comment: After adding new theme you must restart android studio two times to see theme in your Colors and Fonts > Scheme list. (On Android Studio 1.2.2). At least in my case it works.

Comment: Hmm I thought the link is dead since it loads so slow. It is still in beta, that figures.

Comment: Could someone confirm if it still works in Android Studio 2.1.2 (latest version as for now) ? For me, it says that the settings were correctly imported, but the new schemes never show in the Settings.

Comment: @MichaëlPolla I just installed and used this using AS 2.2. The theme didn't show in the settings, but the theme was installed. If you want to see the theme you are using you have to go Preferences > Editor > Color & Fonts > Scheme. That is where you will see the theme you imported. Using Appearance > Theme with change the outer theme, not the text editor. Hope this helps.

Comment: Looks like the link is now dead

Comment: how do I undo this?

Comment: Just as a friendly note: The suggested link will provide editor color themes and *not* IDE themes. Editor color themes will only affect the colors of the program code you're writing in the editor tab. The IDE itself, such as buttons, dialogs and windows, will be unaffected by these.

Comment: There are a few others there too, but not many choices: http://www.androidstudiothemes.com

Comment: I'm on Windows 10, I added a theme from here, and now my text is all scaled very small... any tips?

Comment: Once installed, the themes look very little like they do previewed on the site. I find many themes pleasant on the site but hard to read in Android Studio. The themes I tried hard-baked the font, so I couldn't change that. The colors are clearly different.

Comment: Once you go Solarized, you never go back :D Thanks for the tip! It's still available in 2018.

Answer (score 128):

//you need to go to the File-> settings 
in that choose IDE settings-> Appearance in that choose the Theme: options

[image]

Comment: @bagusflyer dont go to the editor font options. click on Apperance.

Comment: I know where the Apperance is.But I only have two themes to select.You have a lot more.

Comment: @kongkea This is right answer i don't know why you don't selected as right answer

Comment: You have to understand that people who posted this answer really like to brag. Get use to it. They gonna post code and link without explanation. They are so very good at it.

Comment: @ZhouHao I too initally had only two themes, but you can add themes which you download from the internet (as .icls files).

Comment: Very correct solution

Answer (score 43):

**Windows**

> File->Settings->Editor->Colors & Fonts->

**Mac OSX**

> Android Studio -> Preferences->Editor->Colors&Fonts

Answer (score 38):

Dayle Reese has an amazing set of [color schemes available](https://github.com/daylerees/colour-schemes/tree/master/jetbrains) for use in both AndroidStudio and Intellij.  Depending on the IDE you are using, these ICLS files go into a particular directory (*This is for Windows*):

**Android Studio**

> %USERPROFILE%/.AndroidStudio/config/colors

**IntelliJ**

> %USERPROFILE%/.IntelliJIdea/config/colors

Once you've placed the ICLS files in one of the directories above, relaunch the IDE so that it picks up the new themes.  There is also a nice page containing a [preview of most/all the themes](http://daylerees.github.io/) so you can figure out which ones you like most.  Enjoy.

Comment: Thanks! By the way in my case I had to copy these files to %USER_HOME%/.AndroidStudioBeta/config/colors

Comment: @MichaelLiberman Awh yes, I should have updated this after beta released.  Thank you!

Comment: Weird. I have to use %USERPROFILE% as %USER_HOME% isn't set for me (Windows 8.1)

Comment: `%USER_HOME%` is for Gradle and comes from the system property `user.home` in Java. `%UserProfile%` and `%HomeDrive%%HomePath%` are Windows environment variables.

Comment: On Mac this directory is ~/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio/colors

Comment: As of Beta 1.2 this is now %USERPROFILE%/.AndroidStudioPreview1.2

Comment: I've added the .icls files in %USERPROFILE%/.AndroidStudio/config/colors and restarted the IDE. But, I''m not able to see the themes in File->Settings->Editor->Colors & Fonts

Comment: IMPORTANT NOTE: the page with the previews are for php coding colors only. So it's better not to use it, or keep that in mind. For example, "Glowfish" looks completely different on Java when using Android Studio, it's not matrix-green colors like it is for PHP. Best way is to download all then preview yourself

Answer (score 17):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> (Back Quote).
Then select "Switch Color Scheme" or press 1.
Select "Dracula" or press 2.

Comment: Thumbs down for locale unware key shortcuts, let alone OS unaware.

Answer (score 17):

If one just need to change (strictly just) the editor's background to your own colour.

`Preferences` > `Editor` > `Color & Fonts` > `General` > `Default Text` > `Background`

Although you need to save it as your own theme.

Comment: Thanks! I use Darcula but wanted to change my editor background.  This did the trick.

Comment: This is true answer for changing background

Comment: This is what I was looking for !

Answer (score 17):

Just a note for people in the future.
To add more themes on a **Mac**, put the theme .icls files in

```
~/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio/colors/
```

Then restart Android Studio. And select your new themes in

```
Android Studio > Preferences > Editor > Colors&Fonts
```

Android Studio can use any theme that are made for jetbrains IDE. [Here](https://github.com/daylerees/colour-schemes) is a good Github repo that has many themes for different IDEs.

Also, the `Color Ide` plugin is a good tool that changes the background colour of all menus in Android Studio to match your theme. Try it, the IDE will look much better.

Windows should have similar setups, just the theme directory will be a bit different, search for JetBrains Ide theme location should give you the result.

Comment: How can I do the same on Windows?

Comment: In my case this was my location ~/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio2.3 and I had to create the "colors" folder because it didn't exist there.
So the final path was:
~/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio2.3/colors

Answer (score 15):

(Note: the exact paths shown here are primarily for Windows and Linux. I know Mac has a few non-standard paths, so if you're on Mac, you may have to adjust the starting bit of the path. The point is, get into settings however you'd do that on a Mac)

## Switch theme:

File -> Settings-> Appearance & behavior -> Appearance.

Select the "theme" dropdown, and change between whatever themes you have installed. It shows the default themes and any you have installed in the form of plugins.

## Install new themes

### As plugin from plugins.jetbrains.com

File-> Settings -> plugins -> install JetBrains plugin/browse repositories/install plugin from disk

**Note**: newer versions of Android Studio, and possibly IntelliJ, (at least Jan. 2021 and out) may instead have a Marketplace tab in place of the first and/or second one.

The last part has three different options. The first has a few amount of plugins, and looks like only the official plugins. Browse repositories have much more plugins, and seems to be like going to the plugin page. This is a shorter way than going to the intelliJ plugin page and downloading the plugins manually. If you download, click install plugin from disk. This allows you to drag and drop, or find .jar files.

In the install JetBrains plugins, browse repositories, and (newer versions) Marketplace tabs should have a search functionality. You can search for i.e. "theme" from there.

Answer (score 14):

1. Download a color theme you like - some sites host these, and some GitHub repos may offer them as well. [Editor's note: the website previously linked here has been replaced with spam]
2. Import the theme. File -> Import Settings. Navigate to the theme-name.jar. Click the "Ok" button. This will tell you restart your application, at least it did for me, and it automatically selected the theme for my editor.
3. Change the editor's theme color by going to File -> Settings -> Editor -> Colors & Fonts. Select the scheme and click the "Ok" button.

Note that this changes the editor's theme color, not the entire application's theme.

Comment: `File -> File Import Settings`

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Comment: think this is a dud site (07/2017)?

Comment: Edited out the link with some generic stuff -- it redirects to porn atm, so it's not really of value for the rest of the answer

Answer (score 12):

File->Settings->Appearance

There's a dropdown box with various themes.

Comment: Yes this is working in Latest Android Studio all of the above are for previous versions :)

Answer (score 11):

Mac OS

To install new Theme on Mac go to `Preferences -> Plugins -> Browse Repositories ->` Select Category `"UI"` and search theme name, I recommend `"Material Theme UI"` click on the green button `"Install"` and then restart after installation.

If your theme is .icls format.

1. Right click on finder and select "go to folder"
2. type "~/Library/" to go to hidden library folder
3. find "Preferences"
4. find "AndroidStudio2.x"
5. if you don't have "colors" folder then create one
6. paste .icls theme files into colors.

new theme will be installed.

to change themes go to `Preferences -> Editor -> Colors & Fonts` and then select the scheme.

Answer (score 10):

- Go to `File > Settings,`
- now under IDE settings click on `appearance` and select the theme of your choice from the dropdown.
- you can also `install themes`, they are the jar files
  by
- `File > Import Settings`, select the file or your choice and select ok
  a pop up to `restart` the `studio` will open up click yes and studio will restart and your theme will be applied.

Answer (score 10):

For additional themes I visited `https://plugins.jetbrains.com/search?headline=164-theme&tags=Theme` I was able to download one of them. I closed all my tabs opened and simply dragged and dropped the jar file. That was the way Android Studio prompted to restart. I tried importing the jar file as mentioned previously but it simply didn't work.

Answer (score 9):

In 2.3.2 i can change the theme by following

```
View -> Quick Switch Theme -> 6.Look and Feel
```

Comment: Hello i have issue not showing name of class in Left side Porject stucture

Answer (score 8):

Thought I would add this as an answer, for anyone who accidentally mess up like I did!
It't not really an answer to the original question, but a few other posts refer to this post, so thought I would add it here (cause its slightly relevant to the question). Hope it helps someone!

Today I accidentally set my IDE font size on Android Studio very high (was going to set it to *10*, but it accidentally became *110*).

Now, the big issue for me was that opening the file menu was not possible (well, could open it, but could not get to the settings choice), so I had to figure out how to do it manually.

I found the Android Studio IDE settings in the `Users/%username%/.AndroidStudioPreview/config` folder and in there, the `ui.inf.xml` file, in which I could change the option `FONT_SIZE` back to a more manageable size.

*Following image is android studio with 110 px font size on a 1920x1080 screen:*
[image: Android studio 110 px font size]

Answer (score 8):

File->Settings->Appearance & Behavior-> Appearance and In theme select Darcula and apply dark background theme editor.

Answer (score 7):

On OSX, in the menu bar at the top, click on Android Studio > Preferences > Appearance and you will see a theme drop down.

Answer (score 7):

You can try this [Making Android Studio pretty](https://meedamian.com/post/deuglifying-android-studio/) to change the android studio look and feel different.

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for, not just a text color scheme but an IDE theme, very nice awnser :)

Answer (score 7):

In **Android Studio 3.4.2**:

As mentioned in previous answers, you can change theme to Darcula in **Appearance & Behavour > Appearance** to have default dark theme.

Since macOS Mojave you can use dark mode in system. My issue was the system window bar was still light only for Android Studio:

[image]

Note there's an option to change this next to the theme selector: **Use dark window headers**

[image]

Comment: Actually this is the step which completes the theme color change.

Answer (score 7):

To install Custom theme in android studio --version 4.1.2

1. download theme file(.jar) from https://plugins.jetbrains.com/
2. open android studio
3. drag the .jar file into studio

Answer (score 6):

You can use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>  and then simply type `theme` to go directly to the theme settings. Same goes for pretty much any setting, refactoring or action you're looking for.

Answer (score 6):

On Windows:
File-> Settings-> Appearance&Behavior-> Appearance:
Change "**Theme field**".

Answer (score 6):

Simple. Just hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>s</kbd> - appearance & behavior - appearance - Theme - (Darcula)

Answer (score 4):

You can **change or import a theme** by using the icon that the "Duplicate Theme" arrow is pointing to in the photo.

Every one sees color differently. Most times a small change in contrast is all you need. **Removing the hase from Dracula** by changing the *Background color to 242527* was perfect for me.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

well most of these answers tell you about installing currrent theme , I will tell you the easy way to install new theme as of march 22 ,2022 .

- while in android studio press `` ctrl + ` ``
- you may see this option [image: switch] switch
- select Theme from the menu
- then you will see themes installed .
- change this or click on the last option 'install themes' to install new themes directly

Answer (score 3):

File - Settings - Appearance & Behavior - Appearance - CHOOSE Darcula in "Theme" - Press Apply.

**or**

Choose File - Settings - Editor - Colors & Fonts - Then SELECT Darcula in scheme name - Press Apply - restart Studio (sometimes not all elements implement theme)

Answer (score 3):

Mac os : mojave / Android studio 3.5

mac os : Android Studio > Preferences > Editor > Color scheme > Scheme : Darcula

Answer (score 2):

Follow the steps :

1. Go to File -> Settings -> Appearance&Behaviour -> Appearance
2. Change the theme to whatever you like.
3. Then restart the android studio.

Answer (score 2):

For easy reference in Android Studio 3.0.

Click **File > Settings > Appearance & Behaviors > Apperance**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In MacOS:

```
Android Studio -> Preferences... -> Editor -> Color Scheme -> Color Scheme Font
```

Change Scheme to Dracula

Answer (score 2):

**Windows**

> File->Settings->Appearance & behavior->Appearance.

Select the "theme" dropdown, and change between whatever themes you have installed. It shows the default themes and any you have installed in the form of plugins.

**Mac OSX**

> Android Studio -> Preferences->Editor->Colors&Fonts

Select the "theme" dropdown, and change between whatever themes you have installed. It shows the default themes and any you have installed in the form of plugins.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows 7 - 64Bit
File->Settings->Editor->Colors&Fonts-> Use the dropdown box: "Scheme name" and select Darcula.

Answer (score 1):

I've found interesting themes from github.com/jkaving/intellij-colors-solarized. Palette specifications is from ethanschoonover.com/solarized. 
I use one of them in my Android Studio, version 2.1.3

Answer (score 1):

I am using android studio 2.2.3 and I am able to change theme by following steps

1. go to **File > Setting** it open an window like attach image
2. then **Editor > Colors & Fonts**
3. Select theme from **Scheme** dropdownlist
4. now select **Ok**

[image]