# How to change theme of Android Studio for Mac?

Tags: android-studio, googleio

I am trying to find out the way to set the black theme to my newly installed android studio but I didn't get success.

I have seen a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16579448/how-to-change-or-add-theme-to-android-studio) but that is for windows (I am not getting option for settings).

Please tell me how to do same in mac machine.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Android Studio > Preferences > (Under the heading "IDE Settings") Editor > Colors & Fonts > Java > Scheme name

I use Dracula, it's pretty sic

Answer (score 6):

It is related to your question.

[How to change or add theme to Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16579448/how-to-change-or-add-theme-to-android-studio)

For Window:

```
File > Settings > Editor > Colors & Fonts
```

Mac OSX:

```
Android Studio > Preferences > Editor > Colors & Fonts
```

Answer (score 1):

For Mac Users ***(Android Studio 3.3.1)***

> Android Studio > Preferences > Appearance & Behaviour > Appearance > UI Options > Theme

I haven't use Window OS so didn't check but might be below answer will helps you.

[How to change or add theme to Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16579448/how-to-change-or-add-theme-to-android-studio)

Answer (score 1):

**from Android studio, type Cmd + Comma(,) so it will leads you to setting from there click on editor and then ColorScheme.**
Hope its helpful

Answer (score 0):

For Mac OSX:

```
Android Studio > Preferences > Editor > Color Scheme
```

For Window:

```
File > Settings > Editor > Color Scheme
```

From there you can select the options from the drop down menu and click apply and ok.

You can also import custom theme jar files and use them.
To the right of the drop down you get a settings options in which there is an option to Import Scheme.
I am speaking this in respect to the Android Studio in Mac OSX. Ideally it should be the same for the Android Studio on Windows machine as well.

Answer (score 0):

### Android Studio Dolphin on macOS Monterey 12.6

If you need to set custom colors for Editor in Android Studio 2021.3.1, just go to:

<kbd>Android Studio</kbd>-<kbd>Preferences...</kbd>-<kbd>Editor</kbd>-<kbd>Color Scheme</kbd>-<kbd>Kotlin</kbd>

Or, if you need more color themes, just download them using `Get more themes` link from Appearance tab. To change a BG color of any color scheme, go to:

<kbd>Android Studio</kbd>-<kbd>Preferences...</kbd>-<kbd>Editor</kbd>-<kbd>Color Scheme</kbd>-<kbd>General</kbd>-<kbd>Text</kbd>-<kbd>Default Text</kbd>-<kbd>Background</kbd>