# How do I change Android Studio editor's background color?

Tags: android, android-studio

I want the grey shade as shown in previews but mine has white as default. I tried to search in file->settings but without much success. Also, I couldn't find Project->clean or any such option. Any help will be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16579448/1012284

Comment: If you want only change background on whatever theme you are Preferences > Editor > Color & Fonts > General > Default Text > Background. You could not do this on default theme hence you need to create a copy of default theme as android studio will guide you if you click on background selection rectangle.

Answer (score 58):

You can change it by going `File` **=>** `Settings` (Shortcut <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+ <kbd>ALT</kbd>+ <kbd>S</kbd>) , from Left panel Choose `Appearance` , Now from Right Panel choose **theme**.

[image]

**Android Studio 2.1**

> Preference -> Search for Appearance -> UI options , Click on DropDown **Theme**

[image]

**Android 2.2**

> Android studio -> File -> Settings -> Appearance & Behavior -> Look for UI Options

**EDIT :**

**Import External Themes**

> You can download custom theme from [this](https://github.com/sdvoynikov/color-themes) website. Choose your theme, download it. To set theme Go to *Android studio -> File -> Import Settings ->* Choose the `.jar` file downloaded.

Comment: how do i undo adding an external theme

Comment: @karthikprasad You can set to default theme provided by AS - Preference -> Search for Appearance -> UI options , Click on DropDown Theme.

Comment: that is not the answer to the question: I want to solely change the color of the backgorund, not the entire theme

Answer (score 20):

> How do I change Android Studio editor's background color?

**Changing Editor's Background**

```
Open Preference > Editor (In IDE Settings Section) > Colors & Fonts > Darcula or Any item available there
```

IDE will display a dialog like this, Press 'No'

> Darcula color scheme has been set for editors. Would you like to set
>   Darcula as default Look and Feel?

**Changing IDE's Theme**

```
Open Preference > Appearance (In IDE Settings Section) > Theme > Darcula or Any item available there
```

Press OK. Android Studio will ask you to restart the IDE.

Comment: (Mac 10.10.3,  AndroidStudio 1.2.2) This is still relevant, I had to do both of these. Changing just the IDE theme did NOT change the "event log" or the "editor" window.