# How to revert theme from Darcula to default in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, android-theme, android-ide

I have changed my Android Studio theme from Default to Darcula.

But when I want to search anything then I need to go to browser which is very bright.

Now I want to revert the theme from Darcula to default theme in Android Studio. When I do that, it just changes background color and font color of Editor window. I want to change the whole window to be default instead of black.

[image: Bright-themed editor in dark-themed IDE]

**Edited**

I have changed theme from Android Studio | Preferences | Editor | Colors & Fonts.

Check out [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16601260/how-do-i-change-android-studio-editors-background-color) for more detail about how to change theme in Android Studio.

Comment: how you changed theme? FRom settings > appearences right?

Comment: Yes, From Settings->Editor->Color&Fonts in Windows.

Comment: [Reset theme](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30287996/4723795) - answer with explanation.

Answer (score 160, accepted):

You might be tried to change **Settings -> Colors & Fonts -> Scheme name** like below:

[image]

Try to edit **Settings -> Appearances -> Theme**:

[image]

Comment: @deniz , is there any shortcut key to switch the theme?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky , why not? I'm using 2.2 and i faced the same issue. I solved as this answer. :)

Answer (score 17):

This issue often happens after updating `IntelliJ`. In this case switching back to `IntelliJ` theme and to `Darcula` again solves the issue:

`File | Settings | Apperance | Theme | InteliJ, Apply`

`File | Settings | Apperance | Theme | Darcula, Apply`

Answer (score 9):

I installed Android Studio for Mac (Android Studio version 1.5.1)

To toggle between Default and Darcula themes I do:

**Android Studio - Preferences**

Then **write *Theme* on the top-left Search Bar**

And under **Appearance and Behavior - Appearance**
Next to theme you can choose between Default and Darcula themes.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Go to File -> Settings -> Appearance under IDE section ->change theme to intelij or default or windows.
[image]

see [here](http://technikes.com/revert-dracula-theme-to-default-in-android-studio/) for more.

Answer (score 0):

choose **Editor>Color Scheme>Classic Light**

[image]