# Name of default editor theme in android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, atom-editor

I want to know the name of the default editor theme of the android studio. I know that the dark one is called Darcula, but i couldn't find the name of the default theme of android studio. It just says Default or IntelliJ there, but i want to know the name of the specific color theme, or any other color theme that is almost same as the default one

I just started using atom text editor for my other programming tasks, but I love the android studio's default theme. So I want to know the name of the default theme, so that i can use the same editor theme in my other text editors and thanks in advance, for reading

Comment: This looks close.  http://color-themes.com/?view=theme&id=563a1a6e80b4acf11273ae76

Answer (score 2):

The name of default theme is `default`
[image]

```
File->Settings->Editor->Colors & Fonts-
```

or you can customize as you want!

for text editor its intellij
[image]
[How do I change Android Studio editor's background color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16601260/how-do-i-change-android-studio-editors-background-color)

if you can find a .jar of your favorite theme can try this one too http://blog.raychenon.com/2014/07/27/how-to-change-ui-theme-on-intellij-and-android-studio/

Comment: I'm not sure this answers how to use that theme in the Atom Editor

Comment: Thanks for answering but please tell me the name of the theme or the name of some of other theme that resembles the default theme .

Comment: try this with your favorite theme http://blog.raychenon.com/2014/07/27/how-to-change-ui-theme-on-intellij-and-android-studio/

Comment: The question isn't asking how to change the Intellij theme... Question is asking for the color scheme that Intellij uses to export to different editors

Comment: as @cricket_007 said, i want to know the name of the theme, not how to change the theme