# How can I improve my android studio installation?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I decided to check Android Studio since it seems that Eclipse is being phased out. When I installed it in my Mac and opened it, I was surprised at how bad the editor looks.
I was wondering are there any settings/plugins to improve the look and feel of the IDE so that it is as nice as Eclipse? 
Also I can not seem to find something like "Call hierarchy".
What is Android Studio supposed to be used? Just a bare bones editor? How can I improve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was in the same situation a week ago so hopefully I can help.

To change the appearance setting:
File -> settings -> appearance -> Theme (top 1/3 of page). I use Dracula as I like the darker style.

For text I use obsidian.
You can find various themes online. [Editor's note: the website previously linked here containing colorthemes has switched owners and been replaced with spam]

When you've found a theme, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16579448/how-to-change-or-add-theme-to-android-studio/20647946#20647946):

> Once you have downloaded the .jar file, go to File -> Import Settings... and choose the file downloaded.

Since you are coming from eclipse you might want to change the keymaps as well.
File -> settings -> type keymaps in the search bar. I use the eclipse keymap however I rebinded control 1 to "refactor this" like in eclipse.

The closest thing I have found to a call hierarchy so far is the right click "find usages".

I would pay attention to the hints that come up each time you open the editor, they have helped me out a lot.

Comment: Plus One for the Use Eclipse Keymap advice.  This makes for a much easier transition into Android Studio.

Comment: No kidding, I was going crazy the first time I tried to redo (ctrl + y) and I started deleting lines.

Comment: Hah!  I had the opposite issue - trying to delete a line (with ctrl-d, of course) and it duplicated the line instead!

Comment: Android Studio has a "call hierarchy" view ;) in Navigate menu, shortcut key Ctrl+Alt+h

Comment: Thanks for the edit @Zoe, I'm sad that website has been removed. It seems like this might be the best alternative https://plugins.jetbrains.com/search?tags=Theme, at least this is owned by jetbrians.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanna have the call hierarchy just use Ctrl-Alt-H - or check in you keymap preferences

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio is 10x as good as Eclipse. It took about a week to realise it was an improvement, and that's coming from someone to whom losing the ability to code in C++ and NDK was like losing a toe.

It gives you a hint every time you start it. Don't cheat and read them all. Take them one at a time and practise what you learn. You will soon be doubly productive.

With a few good shortcuts I hope to never need to know what a "call hierarchy" was or is. Just Ctrl-B or Ctrl-click to go to declaration, or Alt-F7 for all references. Ctrl-Q for... I forget. Ctrl-F to highlight all occurrences, with a different word highlightable in each file.

I feel you about having extra heigh of menu at the top, the one above the tabs I'd like to remove, but I have a 17" screen so will abide for now.

I'd only go back to Eclipse for NDK stuff, but soon that too will be rolled into Android Studio. I can't praise it enough.

Answer (score 0):

you can switch themes from settings or download few themes for editor online. The default version has two themes light and dark. And if you are familiar with sublime text editor in Mac then you can make Android studio similar like that from [here](http://envyandroid.com/archives/1000/monokai-theme-in-android-studio-and-intellij)