# Intellij 14; Color scheme change ; Not all panes are obeying the change?

Tags: intellij-idea, colors

I have tried to change to Dracula theme. But i find it too dark.
When i revert back to default. Only the editor pane reverts.
Every thing else remains dark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found answer in stackoverflow Reset Intellij UI to Default. Basically delete:

```
.IntellijIdea14\config\options\options.xml
      \laf.xml
      \colors.scheme.xml
```

Answer (score 3):

Navigate to Preferences > Appearance and Behavior > Appearance and change the theme to "Default".

[image]

Then you simply need to restart Android Studio for this to take effect.

And learn how to add them [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16579448/how-to-change-or-add-theme-to-android-studio)

Comment: I did that, and all it's variants ?

Comment: Just added a screenshot, does that help?