# How to add color schemes to Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

I found some links to download the .icls files on the link below. However, just by adding the .icls files to the color folder is not doing the job.

Any pointers in right direction is appreciated. (I found only one dark theme here and looking for light themes).

[How to change or add theme to Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16579448/how-to-change-or-add-theme-to-android-studio)

Answer (score 2):

Found the issue: I was using firefox to download from the site and the site below was giving me a .zip file instead of .jar file. Used Chrome and got the .jar file. [Editor's note: the site previously linked here has changed owners and been replaced with spam, and has been edited out]

Steps to follow:

1. File > Import Settings. Select the .jar file.
2. Close and start Android studio (auto restart didn't work)
3. Settings > Editor > Colors and Fonts select your theme and you are good to go.