# Is it possible to set image background in android studio editor?

Tags: android, android-studio, background-image, android-theme

I wanna customize android studio editor background ,So i want to set image to editor,Is it possible ,Is there any option perform that.?

Comment: did you get or not ?

Comment: no I'm not get it

Answer (score 8):

`IntelliJ IDEA` allows you to define any image as a background. So doing, you can set a background image for the current project only.

**1.To set a background image**

Do one of the following:

Press Shift twice ..

[image]

**2.** In the dialog box that opens, specify the image you want to use as the background, its opacity, filling and placement options. Besides that, you can choose to show background in the editor and tool windows, or in the IntelliJ IDEA frame

[image]

for More detail source is : https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/setting-background-image.html

Comment: how to open above screen

Comment: that is not available for android studio, i think.

Comment: click two times shift key and then time set background. you will have the option to open that screen.

Comment: Works on Android Studio 3.3 Beta 4

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you go on Android studio and open setting
You get appearance menu and their first subMenu  you click and get a background option you can click and use wallpaper as your wish....

Answer (score 0):

With the new **Android Studio 2.3** Canary build you can do it,

check http://tools.android.com/recent/androidstudio23canaryavailable

> IDE: We've upgraded the base IDE from IntelliJ 2016.1 to 2016.2, which
>   adds a number of new features -- ligatures, breadcrumbs, editor
>   background images, revamped UI for inspections, notifications and the
>   debugger, and more.

However you should also check [How to change or add theme to Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16579448/how-to-change-or-add-theme-to-android-studio)