# Android Studio displaying activity incorrectly in editor

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity

My son and his friend (both 12) are teaching themselves programming on Android (they already have some Java experience).

When Nic edits an activity it looks like this:
[image]

This is fine, but when Max displays his activity for editing it looks like this:

[image]

This is a problem and Max is really struggling to build and design his activities. Is there any way to change the display to the first look and feel? I have looked around within the IDE and can't find it anywhere.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16579448/how-to-change-or-add-theme-to-android-studio this might help

Comment: Hi Abhishek, thanks for the response but I am not talking about the black background. I am talking about the design screen section where the second design screen has a ruler around it and the way to add elements onto the screen doesn't really work.

Comment: Are they both using the same OS and same version of Android Studio?

Comment: Are you 100% sure Max is displaying the same Activity? Also I think Max's AS version is higher than Nic's, if you want them to have the exact same experience, they should be on the same versions. Also, from what I can see in the screenshots, they are displaying previews for different SDK versions (24 vs 25) although that shouldn't really matter here.

Comment: Oh, sorry, just noticed it's not about one Activity being displayed in a different way, but about the whole editor. So I think it's different Android Studio versions problem.

Comment: Okay thanks for the info guys. I think we will have to accept that it is a different versions. I am surprised at how different they look. In my opinion the older version is better but it is what it is. Regards, Martin.