# How to change Completion Background In Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0

Is there any way to change the suggestion background color?

[image]

Comment: I'v researched in Preferences (on Mac) that here can change editor color, but it doesn't allow us to change Completion Background as your terminology. I'd suggest you search "Intention action" and "Intellij theme editor" keyword.

Answer (score 0):

The default themes provided in Android Studio are the "Default" white theme and the "Darcula" theme that can be changed from the Preferences > Appearance & Behavior > Appearance. There are more theming options that you can use for Android Studio by downloading a .jar file:

> You can download new themes from https://github.com/sdvoynikov/color-themes
>
> Once you have downloaded the .jar file, go to File -> Import Settings... > and choose the file downloaded.**strong text**

see: [How to change or add theme to Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16579448/how-to-change-or-add-theme-to-android-studio)

Comment: its not the perfect ans