# How to apply a lighter background to Darcula theme in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

In Darcula, when the font color is also dark - as in the green below - then it is hard to read against the pitch black background and bugs hide in the undergrowth.

Is there a way to change the background from pitch black to a lighter shade, for example gray (without the glare from the default theme)?

[image]

Comment: Try this theme : https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8006-material-theme-ui

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to `Settings` > `Editor` > `Color scheme` > `General`

Select `Text` > `Default text`

Change background color from the right panel

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As La Bla Bla suggested, you can customise the theme in settings.

OR you could download an entirely new theme from JetBrains' selection here:

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/search?tags=Theme

and import it using these steps:

[How to change or add theme to Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16579448/how-to-change-or-add-theme-to-android-studio)

Comment: too many themes on that web page, and no descriptions of each.